# Can not get ExportLInks when listing files using Drive API based on 2-legged oAuth

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I got one issue when listing files of GoogleApps user using GoogleDrive API.

```
public void getFiles(String serviceAccount) throws Exception {
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
            .setServiceAccountId(serviceAccount)
            .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE))
            .setServiceAccountUser("xxx@xxx.com")
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new java.io.File(new URI(ServiceTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource("googledrive.p12").toString())))
            .build();

    credential.refreshToken();

    Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)
         .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).setApplicationName("GoogleDrive").build();

    FileList result = service.files().list().setMaxResults(1000).execute();
    List<File> files = result.getItems();
    if (files != null && files.size() > 0) {
        for (File file : files) {
            System.out.println(file.getTitle()+","+file.getId()+","+file.getExportLinks());
        }
    }
}
```

The reponse is good, and I can get all the files successfully including fileid, fiename, parentid.... 
But all files' exportLinks are NULL (most of these files have exportLinks when I using 3-legged oAuth).

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I tried to replicate the problem, but I'm getting exportLinks for my files, even when using a service account. Are you only seeing this for certain file types?